# How to calculate diff in quantity some value between months?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE month_c (
                     id int not null primary key,
                     quantity int not null,
                     created TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO month_c
(id, quantity, created)
VALUES
(1, 2, '2020-01-03 11:01:01'),
(2, 1, '2020-01-03 14:23:33'),
(3, 1, '2020-02-03 14:23:33'),
(4, 2, '2020-02-03 14:23:33'),
(5, 4, '2020-02-03 14:23:33'),
(6, 4, '2020-03-03 14:23:33'),
(7, 5, '2020-04-03 14:23:33'),
(8, 5, '2020-05-03 14:23:33'),
(9, 6, '2020-05-03 14:23:33');
```

and this query can calculate how much quantity was per each month

```
select
    sum(m.quantity),
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created) as month
FROM month_c as m
GROUP BY month
```

there is result:

```
sum, month
4   3
11  5
5   4
3   1
7   2
```

But main goall calculate diff between mont and next month, between january and february, february and macrh, march and april and result should will be like that:

```
sum, month
4   3
+7  5
-6  4
-2  1
+4  2
```

does it possible to execute it in pg query ?

Comment: Check again your expected results, because they are wrong.

Comment: yep, missed sort by month

Comment: No, this is not the problem. The differences in the sums are wrong also.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't match your output, but your output doesn't appear to be sorted by month, which I am hoping is a mistake.

I believe what you want can be achieved with the `lag` analytic function:

```
with cte as (
  select
    sum(m.quantity) as qty,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created) as month
  FROM month_c as m
  GROUP BY month
)
select
  month, qty,
  qty - lag (qty, 1, 0::bigint) over (order by month) as delta
from cte
```

Results:

```
Month     Qty    Delta
1           3       3
2           7       4  (delta between 3 and 7)
3           4      -3  (delta between 7 and 4)
4           5       1
5          11       6
```

> LAG(expression [,offset [,default_value]])  OVER (
> [PARTITION BY partition_expression, ... ]
> ORDER BY sort_expression [ASC | DESC], ... )

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do in your query is to subtract the previous month's sum which you can get with `LAG()` window function:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) - LAG(SUM(quantity)::int, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created)) AS "sum",
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created) AS month
FROM month_c as m
GROUP BY month
```

If the table contains data for more than 1 year, you should group by `to_char(created, 'YYYY-MM')` instead of `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created)`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=46effd497e3580dd9d2bcc3d4b9cd1c7).
Results:

| sum | month |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| -3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |